# How to turn a column of characters into a column of lists

Tags: r, dataframe, list

In order to save a dataframe as a csv file, I had to convert a list-type column of the dataframe that was a list of vectors of different lengths and of different dates.
ex.
[image]

To be able to save the dataframe, I did `DF$dates <- as.character(DF$dates)` and then used `write.csv()` to save it.  I want to be able to read in this file and use this column as a list column of vectors again, but the resulting column after reading in the file is a column of characters that is difficult to work with.
The rows are all variations of this: `c("12/01/23", "12/02/23", "12/04/23", "12/05/23", "12/07/23", "12/13/23", "12/14/23", "12/15/23", "12/16/23", "12/17/23", "12/19/23", "12/20/23", "12/21/23", "12/22/23", "12/23/23", "12/24/23", "12/25/23", "12/30/23", "12/31/23")"` which is just one long string that I am not able to use for much.

I've tried several things such as `as.list()` on a cell, using `str_sub()` to remove the parentheses, `str_replace_all()` to replace the backslashes, and `strsplit()` to separate the dates into different list objects and nothing has been simple or worked well enough.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include reproducible data? A good approach would be something like `dput(DF[1:5,])`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-parse the contents of "dates" (`c()` and all) as an expression and reattach it in the following way. I'm not sure if you're using **dplyr** or not, so here is a base R solution:

```
DF <- data.frame(dates = 'c("12/01/23", "12/02/23", "12/04/23", "12/05/23", "12/07/23", "12/13/23", "12/14/23", "12/15/23", "12/16/23", "12/17/23", "12/19/23", "12/20/23", "12/21/23", "12/22/23", "12/23/23", "12/24/23", "12/25/23", "12/30/23", "12/31/23")')

DF$dates_list <- lapply(DF$dates, \(x) eval(str2expression(x)))
```